# Iterating over a map and putting its values in java

Tags: java, guava

I have created the data structure that is google based guava table and it is  shown below

```
    final Table<String, String, List<String>> values = HashBasedTable.create();
    values.put("ton bon", "currency", Lists.newArrayList("ccdd", "rode1", "cwey", "Certy"));
    values.put("ton bon", "racy", Lists.newArrayList("wqadd", "werde", "ihtr", "ytre"));
```

Below is the way in which i am iterating over this collection

```
    Map<String, List<String>> fmap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> validColumnKeys = Arrays.asList("ccdd", "rode1", "cwey", "Certy");
    Map<String, List<String>> row = values.row("ton bon");
    for (String columnKey : validColumnKeys) {
        fmap.put(columnKey, row.get(columnKey));
    }
```

Now i want to modify my condition in such a way that if the row key contains the value of ton bon and the column key contains these values `"ccdd","rode1","cwey","Certy"` then it should fill the map
named `fmap` as shown below and similarly for the second condition too.

The map i want :

```
Key        Value 
ccdd        currency
rode1       currency
cwey        currency    
Certy       currency
wqadd       racy
werde       racy
ihtr        racy
ytre        racy
```

But unfortunately the code I have tried is not working. Please advise what went wrong and how can I overcome from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Should be a loop inside loop for column and row

```
final Table<String, String, List<String>> values = HashBasedTable.create();
values.put("ton bon", "currency", Lists.newArrayList("ccdd","rode1","cwey","Certy"));
values.put("ton bon", "racy", Lists.newArrayList("wqadd","werde","ihtr","ytre"));
Map<String, List<String>> row = values.row("ton bon");
Map<String, String> fmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
System.out.println("Key\tValue");
for(String columnKey:row.keySet()) {
    List<String> rowValues = row.get(columnKey);
    for(String rowValue:rowValues) {
        System.out.println(rowValue + "\t" + columnKey);
        fmap.put(rowValue, columnKey);
    }
}
```

will print

```
Key     Value
wqadd   racy
werde   racy
ihtr    racy
ytre    racy
ccdd    currency
rode1   currency
cwey    currency
Certy   currency
```

The values can be stored in fmap.put(rowValue, columnKey);.....Note: here the key should be unique

The optimized method is

```
final Table<String, String, List<String>> values = HashBasedTable.create();
values.put("ton bon", "currency", Lists.newArrayList("ccdd","rode1","cwey","Certy"));
values.put("ton bon", "racy", Lists.newArrayList("wqadd","werde","ihtr","ytre"));

Collection<Map<String,List<String>>> obj = Collections2.transform(Collections2.filter(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ton bon"}), Predicates.in(values.rowMap().keySet()) ), Functions.forMap(values.rowMap()));
System.out.println("Key\tValue");
for(Map<String,List<String>> item: obj){
    for(String key: item.keySet()){
        List<String> items = item.get(key);
        for(String value: items){
            System.out.println(value + "\t" + key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to place these value in a map named row which will be of <String>,<String> that is the above generated values please advise how to achieve this

Comment: I have edit the code, you can introduce a map and put the values inside it, The left side printed values should be unique

Comment: Thanks a lot but still please advise why array list named validColumnValues is still there since it is duplicate one I have already added in the values table also values.put("ton bon", "currency", Lists.newArrayList("ccdd", "rode1", "cwey", "Certy"));

Comment: It was actually your code, if you want to validate an existing values against a known set of values, then you should pass the new values externally because logically you don't know which column key it belongs to, if you don't want to do the validation then the first set of code in my answer is enough

Comment: since the second key is racy and its value is not printed

Comment: yes, your input values does not belong to racy, it belongs to currency, if you remove the condition inside then you can remove the duplicate values then it will print all the values without any condition, if need more discussion come to discussion in "Java" chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81182/discussion-between-zigma-empire-and-user1906154).